# Was sagt man auf Deutsch, wenn man die Zunge rausstreckt?

Tags: single-word-request

Die Situation: zwei Kinder streiten, oder Erwachsene benehmen sich scherzhaft kindisch. Person A stiehlt den letzten Schokobonbon von Person B's Tüte. B sagt "Hey, gib's zurück" und A streckt die Zunge aus und sagt... was?

Ich glaube, in solchen Fällen ein Wort gehört zu haben, was wie 'Elebetsch' klingt. Aber ich finde es nirgendwo auf dem Internet, wahrscheinlich schreibe ich es falsch. Was ist denn dieses Wort?

Oder gibt es andere solche Wörter, die anders klingen, aber häufig benutzt werden in dieser Situation?

Comment: Da ich den starken Verdacht hege, dass hier regionale Unterschiede eine Rolle spielen: vielleicht könnten alle Antwortenden einen Hinweis zur Herkunft oder zum Dialekt hinzufügen? Damit man nicht immer im (nicht befüllten) Profil nachschauen muss?

Comment: Da man zum Sprechen die Zunge benötigt, sagt man in dieser Situation gar nichts.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: sag' ich ja. Aber gehen wir mal von sequentiellen Ereignissen aus, was sagst Du, wenn die Zunge wieder zurück im Mund ist?

Comment: Auf dem Internet? Oben drauf? Ich suche wenn, dann im Internet.

Comment: Auf dem Markt, auf dem Fest, auf der Reise, auf dem Bahnhof, auf dem Weg, auf dem Internet. Mir gefällt's. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Klingt nach Dialekt: 
Hier im Schwäbischen sagt man (<sup>1</sup>) **"Ätsch-Bätsch"** oder **"Ätschebätsch"**. Allerdings eignet sich der Ausdruck besser als Begleitung zur "Lange-Nase-machen"-Geste oder zur  "Hände-neben-den-Ohren-wackeln"-Geste, weil man mit rausgestreckter Zunge so undeutlich spricht ;-)

Für diesen Anwendungsfall würde sich ein simples "Bääääääähhhhh" oder "Bläääääähhhh" besser eignen.

---

(<sup>1</sup>) Also man sagt das natürlich nicht, weil sich das schließlich nicht gehört, aber wenn man denn würde...

Comment: Ich (aus Rheinland-Pfalz) kenne es als **Äätschibäätsch**.

Comment: In Österreich (zumindest Graz und Wien): **Ätschibätsch** (beide ä sind kurz, Fugenlaut ist ein i). Es gibt auch ein Spiel mit diesem Namen: http://www.amazon.de/Bartl-GmbH-Ätschibätsch/dp/B001L4CPOI

Comment: Ich denke auch, dass diese Interjektion nicht nur von schwäbischen Kindern benutzt wird: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aetsch__baetsch http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aetsch

Comment: Deshalb ja meine Frage nach der Herkunft der Poster - und weil OP auch nach anderen Wörtern fragte (siehe Barth Z.s Antwort).

Answer (score 7):

Das "Elebetsch" aus der Frage ist Fränkisch: **"Ällabätsch"**

Quelle z.B: Der Song [Ällabätsch](http://www.jbo.de/lyrics/aellabaetsch/) von J.B.
O., mit vielen "Anwendungsbeispielen".

Comment: Siehe auch Dialektwörterbuch: https://multi-deutsch.de/woerterbuch-a-h/

Comment: Ich kenne „Ällabätsch" aus meiner Kindheit in München. Beleg: persönliche Erfahrung ;)

Comment: Gefolgt von "Nänä nänä näh näh" +1 heisst so viel wie "hast du davon" und "kriegst mich eh nicht"

Answer (score 1):

Was ich kenne und gerne benutze, ist

> Pustekuchen!

Answer (score 1):

Ich komme aus Rheinlandpfalz und würde (soweit man mit einer rausgestreckten Zunge eben reden kann, oder jedenfalls nach oder vor dem Rausstrecken) "Ätschibätschi" mit langem ä und i sagen. Nur generell habe ich seit sehr langer Zeit niemandem mehr die Zunge rausgestreckt, weil das als unhöflich gilt und das eigentlich nur Kinder machen.